# Reducing a table by picking one of each unique value from a column

Tags: sqlite

My data from table 'test' looks like this:

```
    A 3
    C 3
    B 4
    D 3
    D 4
```

I'm looking to filter it into this:

```
    A 3
    B 4
```

where every unique value of column 2 is listed, along with an arbitrarily picked value from column 1.  So, this would be a valid output as well:

```
    C 3
    B 4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if column names and data :

```
Col_A   Col_B
A        3
C        3
B        4
D        3
```

then this query

```
select min(colA), Col_B from tableName group by Col_B
```